# C++ fmt library installation is not working

Tags: command-line, permissions, c++, libraries

I'm a new C++ user and I have been facing some problems to install external libraries in my programs. Currently, I'm trying to install the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library. I downloaded the repository content and unpack it. Then I add de sub-directory `fmt` to `usr/include/fmt`, which doesn't work. I also tried add `fmt` to `usr/local/include`, also without success. Here is a sample code and the respective error that returns:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format.h> // I also tried include <fmt/format.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string s = fmt::format("{0}{1}{0}", "abra", "cad");
   cout<< s<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

error:

```
stack.cpp:3:10: fatal error: format.h: No such file or directory
 #include <format.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

I note that the `fmt` folder is "closed" (marked with a "X") after the command I use to transfer it to `usr/~` using:

```
cp fmt-master/include/fmt usr/local/include/fmt
```

I tried to change the folder permissions using:

```
sudo chmod -rwx usr/local/include/fmt
```

But EVEN this didn't work. The command runs without output and `fmt` folder continues with X mark.
I would like to know 1) Save the library folder in `/usr/include` is the standard procedure to install external libraries in C++? (It looks too manual to me) 2) What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `#include "format.h"` or `#include "fmt/format.h"`?

Comment: I just tried `#include "format.h"` and `#include "fmt/format.h"`. It didn't work

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the `libfmt-dev` package from `apt`? You need to enable the universe repository: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: I don't know about that. Where can I find it?

Comment: You can run: `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then: `sudo apt update` and then, `sudo apt install libfmt-dev`

Comment: Thank you! I tried these commands but get the error `Unable to locate package libfmt-dev`. I'm trying to solve this now but your suggestion took me out of the black hole. Only one more question: `apt` is the standard way to install libraries in C++?

Comment: @Hartnäckig Yes, `apt` is the standard way of installing pretty much everything on Ubuntu. I'm running 18.04. If it cannot find the package, try running all three commands again. When you use `apt` to install stuff, everything usually "just works".

Comment: @Hartnäckig One more thing that will help, you can also install `apt-file` to help you find files that you need. `sudo apt install apt-file` and then update it: `sudo apt-file update` and then to search for the file: `apt-file search /usr/include/fmt/format.h` This should show you what package contains the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most packages and libs don't need to be manually downloaded and installed on Ubuntu. You can install `libfmt-dev` using the somewhat official "universe" repository using `apt`.

Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

Most of the "build" type packages in the Ubuntu repositories have the "dev" suffix at the end. 9 times out of 10, when you need to install some prerequisite or dependency to build stuff using g++ or C++, these will be the "lib" packages that you need.

To search for available packages, you can use the `apt-cache search` command like in this example:

```
apt-cache search libfmt
```

If you get too many results, you can pipe the command to `grep` to narrow the results like this:

```
apt-cache search libfmt | grep dev
```

or something like this:

```
apt-cache search fmt | grep 'C+'
```

or you can use the `-i` flag with `grep` so that it is not case sensitive like this:

```
apt-cache search fmt | grep -i 'c+'
```

Comment: In header only mode, I get `/usr/include/fmt/format.h:4007:11: fatal error: 'format.cc' file not found`. So the install is incomplete it seems.

Comment: @Michel `apt-file search format.cc` returns two packages. We usually need the packages with the "dev" suffix so my guess it that this will fix the error: `sudo apt install libspdlog-dev` The other package is `c++-annotations` but it looks like that one just has an example file.

Comment: @Michel See [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205765/c-fmt-library-instalation-is-not-working/1205769#comment2023223_1205765) on how to install `apt-file`